# WordPress categories are taking huge time in page load

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am getting my categories with json encode and so my formatted data is json format, and that data is being used in mobile app, at the moment every thing is working fine except categories. Categories are taking 8 to 10 seconds to load.
here is my data I have written to achieve this task

```
public function category() {
    global $post; global $cate_id;
    if(isset($_GET['category_id'])){
        $cat_id = $_GET['category_id'];
        //$cat = get_category($cat_id);
        //$cat_name = $cat->slug;
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'category' => $cat_id
        //'category_name' => 'cancer-care'
        );
        $posts = get_posts($args);
    }
        //print_r($posts);
        if(!empty($posts)){
            foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post );
                $post_title = $post->post_title;  
                $post_content = $post->post_excerpt;  
                $post_fullcontent = apply_filters ("the_content", $post->post_content);//$post->post_content;  
                $post_link = get_the_permalink($post->ID);
                $post_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ,'thumbnail_size');
                $post_image_thumb = get_bloginfo('template_url').'/thumbs/timthumb.php?src='.$post_image.'&w=438&h=220&zc=1&a=c&q=100';

                $category_name = get_cat_name(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'home_page_category', true));
                $category_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'home_page_category', true);
                $category_color = categoryCustomFields_GetCategoryCustomField($category_id, 'Color Code');
                $category_url = get_category_link(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'home_page_category', true));

                //earlier done: echo $totalcount = $this->social_shares($post_link);

            $result[]  = array(
                'post_id'=>$post->ID,
                'post_title' => $post_title,
                'post_short_content' => $post_content,
                'post_full_content' => $post_fullcontent,
                'post_link' => $post_link,
                'post_image' => $post_image,
                'post_image_thumb' => $post_image_thumb,
                'category_name' => $category_name,
                'category_color_code' => $category_color[0]->field_value ? $category_color[0]->field_value : '#83ab44', 
                'category_id' => $category_id, 
                'category_url' => $category_url,
                'total_social_share' =>$this->social_shares($post_link),
                'post_by' =>get_the_author(),
                'post_date' =>date('Y-m-d', strtotime($post->post_date)),
                'post_time' =>date('H:i:s', strtotime($post->post_date))
            );
            endforeach;
            $message = array(
                "success" => "true",
                "error" => "null",
                "post_data" => $result
            ); 
            echo json_encode(array('response' => $message));
        }else{
            $message = array(
                "success" => "false",
                "error" => "Record not available",
                "post_data" => "Record not available"
            ); 
            echo json_encode(array('response' => $message));
        }
}
```

As soon as go with all my other data like `home_psots` function to show home posts, or `feature_post` function to show featured posts etc are showing results abruptly ... instead categories ... as I am getting categories like this one 
category?category_id=4 any idea so that I can get my data faster than this one ... ??? I have tried a lot of things, even played with `.htaccess` file to redirect to other functions which I wrote but in vain ...:(

Comment: The problem could be this `categoryCustomFields_GetCategoryCustomField` function...  Can you provide it's code?

Comment: thanks for your answer but that's not the case .. even if I comment that whole line it still throws that 10 seconds at me :(

Comment: Commenting the 4 lines starting with `$categories...` solve it?

Comment: Hm... the only advise I can give you now is try to find the problematic part. Commenting the foreach makes it fast enough? Maybe `get_posts` is the slow part...

Comment: get_posts is not the culprit ... the culprit part looks like the argument in the url ... because if I go with only category function and add a static category slug or id then it loads abruptly ... as soon as I go dynamic like getting category_id from url it slows down to 10 second ... hope you get by know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the whole difference in your page load time. Other pages which are loading without URL parameter are being cached and takes less time in further loadings. While W3 Total Cache Plugin does not cache query based URis when Disk Enhanced page cache method is used. That's why your query based pages are not being cached and every time you load your page its being fetched again and takes time. Hope you got the point, to make it cache you can apply other techniques like you can create category page and cache that page where your required category can be shown etc. For further reading here is an other reply from Plugin author himself https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-w3-total-cache-cache-query-urls-disabled
Hope that makes sense by now.

Comment: got your point, let me try any of the other way like categories by slug, if that works

Comment: Wow it works great now, I created category-cancer-care.php page for my cancer-care categories and it shows and caches page really nice and loading times comes down to 2 seconds .... In this way I will be creating other templates for categories ... thanks you so much you are my hero as you saved my job ...

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts):

> Note: The posts_per_page parameter does NOT work without setting the offset parameter

Maybe wordpress is querying all the posts within the category and that is slowing down.

Try this code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'offset' => 0,
    'category' => $cat_id,
);
```

And remember that `'category'`expects the category ID, i.e., an integer.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes I knew but I am doing same in all my functions and all are giving good speed, though I have updated the code added offset now but still time is there the issue ...

Comment: Can you provide the edit that makes code running faster?

Comment: that's almost same data ... the only difference is that I am getting id number from URL in above case while in home_posts function I am using almost same code as shown above

Comment: Are you using any caching method in your other functions which loads faster than category function

Comment: Yes we are using W3 Total Cache plugin to cache our website, all goes really well except this category function